# How to properly format JSON string in Codeiginiter?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My Codeiginiter application retrieves the data from database and stores it in the $result variable and this is then converted to JSON and I get code below:

```
 $data = $query->result_array();  
    $result['result'] = $data;



   { "result":[
    {"name":"John","surname":"Smith"}] }
```

However I want to get following JSON code but didn't have any success. Count represents number of rows. Any ideas? Thanks

```
{
"count": 8,
"result":[
{"name":"John","surname":"Smith"}] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're calling `json_encode` on the `$result` array?

Try the following:

```
$data = $query->result_array();  
$result['result'] = $data;
$result['count'] = count($data);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Hi, I am still gettig JSON Response:  { "result":[
    {"name":"John","surname":"Smith"}] }

Comment: Are you sure you are encoding the same variable?  Have you tried printing out `$result['count']` and `var_dump`ing the `$result` array to be sure it is as you expect?

Comment: I used Firebug and the above response was received from server.

Comment: The above will at worst produce an empty `count` entry in the JSON, and that is with no results.  Are you certain you have updated the file on the server, cleared your cache, etc?  Seems very strange that code you are adding has no effect.

Comment: I just had to change order:

$result['count'] = count($data);
$result['result'] = $data;

and now it works. Thank you

Comment: So it's working?  Great :)  Feel free to mark the answer as correct